# Issue with qemu and gdb

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, qemu

I have a device driver that is freezing the OS. The mouse wont even move. I am trying to debug this issue and I believe one good approach is to use gdb with qemu, two things I have never used before. Is there a better approach?

So first I need to compile the kernel with debug symbols which I have done already.

Now, there is a new file that is generated called vmlinux that is located in that same folder as the source. It seems that I also need a bzImage file [according to this](http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-qemu-to-debug-kernel.html)  so I can run the newly compiled kernel using:

```
qemu-system-i386 -kernel bzImage
```

or in debug mode

```
qemu-system-i386 -s -S -kernel bzImage
```

I cannot locate the bzImage file. Where do I find it or what is missing here? Is the bzImage referring to the OS Image I created using qemu-img create?

Also, what I do not understand is that now the kernel is compiled (vmlinux) how does I run it with qemu? So my question is when I run it with qemu or the debugger is the kernel running as an app in my main OS?

also how can I install my device driver? My understanding the kernel is not Ubuntu so there is no UI?

Also, I installed qemu and when I type qemu I get command not found. I am guessing I have to pick a specific processor emulator as in qemu-system-i386, qemu-system-x86_64, or qemu-x86_64?

How is qemu different or similar to the kvm command?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably looked through the system log when you had rebooted the system after it froze? Were there any messages about kernel errors there? If you did not, I would recommend doing so. Sometimes, it could be easier to start with analysis of the system log than go the route you have described.

Comment: If no information about the failure was saved in the system log, you can try to obtain it another way. If the faulty driver can run in a guest OS (you use Ubuntu as it seems) in a virtual machine, you can configure that OS at boot to output the log to the serial port and retrieve it from there on your host machine. If the driver is for the hardware not supported by the virtual machines, QEMU won't help either.

Comment: Concerning QEMU and KVM, see their official sites: [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page), [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page). In short, QEMU allows to create virtual machines, it emulates the target system. When used with KVM (a set of special kernel modules, etc.), QEMU gains the ability to use the virtualization support of the host CPUs instead of emulation and thus achieve much better performance of the OSes running in the VMs.

Comment: nothing is in the kern.log. not sure if there is any other file I should look into. I am merely guessing but I think its a deadlock as opposed to a crash which is why maybe there is nothing in the kern.log.

Comment: The driver is not even for a hardware, its a tracing tool that intercepts file system calls and basically logs them. Then the driver makes the lower level file system call to perform the actual operation. It is actually better for me if I can log the "file system" calls (at the ext3-4 level). So if there is a way I can trace those calls that can solve my problem too. Thanks.

Comment: I have collected my suggestions in my answer, see below. I have been using the tools and techniques described there for quite some time. They help me a lot to debug the tools I develop that reveal various kinds of errors in the kernel modules ([KEDR](http://code.google.com/p/kedr/), [KernelStrider](http://code.google.com/p/kernel-strider/)).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33203642/895245

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if I understand the problem correctly, you have a kernel module that needs no specific hardware. When you are working with the module, the system freezes but the kernel log contains nothing special.

The following may be helpful.

### Getting the log

The symptoms you described may still be a result of a kernel oops or panic. The logging facilities sometimes die before they can output the information about the error to the log file. You may try to output the log via a serial port, this should be more reliable.

As your kernel module does not need any specific hardware, the easiest way is probably to install the same Linux distro as you use to a virtual machine and connect the virtual serial port (COM) of that machine to a pipe on your host system.

This is usually quite easy to do. For example, [this blog post](http://linuxdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/05/debugging-linux-kernel-over-serial-port.html) contains the detailed instructions in case the host OS and the guest OS are Ubuntu 11.10.

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is used there to manage the virtual machines. If you prefer QEMU, this should be possible as well. I suppose it is a bit easier to go with VirtualBox though but it is a matter of personal preference.

Basically, you need to perform the following steps.

- Create a virtual machine and install the Linux distro you need as a guest OS there.
- Enable a serial port (COM1, ...) in the configuration of the virtual machine and configure it to connect to a special file on the host ("host pipe"), say `/tmp/vbox_serial`.
- Start the guest OS and adjust its boot options: at least, add `console=ttyS0,115200` or something like that to the kernel options in the boot loader menu.
- On the host, start `minicom`, `socat` or whatever else to read from `/tmp/vbox_serial`.
- That is it. Now you should get the kernel log of the guest OS pouring to your host system via `/tmp/vbox_serial`. If the guest system crashes then, you will get the log even if it is not saved into a file on the guest itself.

To make things easier, you may use `socat` on your host system rather than `minicom` that the author of that blog post suggests. The power of `minicom` is probably not needed here.

This way, you can use `socat` and `tee` to save the log to `guest.log` file while still outputting it to the console:

```
socat /tmp/vbox_serial - | tee guest.log
```

If there was a kernel oops or panic, the backtrace in the log usually helps to find out what
has gone wrong.

### Detecting Deadlocks

If you have obtained the full log via a serial connection or some other means and still there is nothing suspicious there and you suspect there has been a deadlock in the kernel,
`lockdep` tool may help. It is included into the kernel (but you may need to rebuild the kernel with `CONFIG_LOCKDEP_SUPPORT=y`).

Lockdep detects the potential deadlocks and outputs the results to the kernel log. [This presentation](http://linuxplumbersconf.org/2011/ocw//system/presentations/153/original/lockdep-plumbers-2011.odp) may help you analyse its output.

### Tracing Facilities

If you need tracing of some events in the kernel to debug your system, there are some tools that could be handy.

- [Kprobes](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kprobes.txt) - a kind of breakpoints you can set in almost arbitrary place in the kernel. Can be used to trace function calls among other things, with a moderate performance impact.
- [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/) - a powerful system to analyze what is going on in the kernel. Part of it is based on Kprobes.
- [Ftrace](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) - a tracing system included into the kernel, incurs less overhead than Kprobes if that matters.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question. What gets printed through the serial port? What I am seeing is a portion of the kernel messages (kern.log) and not all of them. What is strange though is that my module prints a bunch of statements (50 or so per file call) and only a couple gets printed to the serial port. However, in the kern.log all are there. Even the boot messages, not all are there. Actually some  show up in minicom but not in the kern.log and vice versa. So what am I missing here? Thanks again.

Comment: It is hard to guess without seeing your code. Perhaps, it has something to do with log level you use to print these messages (`KERN_INFO`, `KERN_ERR` and the like in `printk()` or `pr_*()` wrappers around `printk`). It depends on the kernel settings, which messages are printed to the console (incl. serial console) and which - to the log file. Usually the messages with level `KERN_CRIT` or higher go both to the console and to the log file, the rest - to the log file only. You can try to add `ignore_loglevel` kernel option at boot, after `console=ttyS0`.

Comment: (continued) This way all messages should go to the serial console. As for the messages absent from the log file - as I suggested before, the logging daemon does not always succeed with saving the messages in the log file, esp. if something wrong happens to the kernel proper or the drivers. The output via serial connection is more reliable.

Comment: Yeah. I noticed KERN_CRIT  in printk. So I finally got the guess OS to freeze and got some feedback from minicom which I will paste in the next comment. So it looks like a deadlock from netbeans although I have no idea why.

Comment: [  108.276531] Process java (pid: 1837, ti=e8824000 task=e880b2c0 task.ti=e8824)
[  108.276531] Stack:                                                           
[  108.276531] Call Trace:                                                      
[  108.276531] Code: 90 b8 43 64 03 c1 b9 40 64 03 c1 e9 49 ff ff ff 90 55 ba 0 
[  136.272032] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [java:1837]              
and another one but ended with this:
[  142.920010] INFO: rcu_sched detected stall on CPU 0 (t=15000 jiffies). Thanks for all your help. It is really appreciated.

Comment: Actually could the stalling messages be from virtual box? or these stalling messages are coming from my guess OS, as in a java process inside my guest OS?

Comment: The messages come from the guest OS. It looks like the call trace got omitted when you pasted the log. Could you add these potions of the log to your question, including the call trace? It would be easier to read than if they are in the comments. Or you can use something like pastebin.com.

Comment: If you suspect there is a deadlock somewhere, you can rebuild the kernel with lockdep enabled as I suggested above and see what it reports. Besides that, if it is OK for you to post the source code or the lonks to it here, that would help a lot.

Comment: There is actually no call trace or stack that is being printed in the serial port. The only thing lost in the formatting above is that the new lines are missing. I ran it again and now a different process is stalling. So this means that my module is hogging the resources from other processes. My next step is to check the deadlock issue as you have suggested. The software is [tracefs](http://www.filesystems.org/project-tracefs.html) but I have ported it to the 3.2 kernel so I suspect some of my changes are causing this issue.