# How to interrupt an infinite loop running in qemu+gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb, qemu

I am using qemu to emulate a sparc V8 machine and using this as a remote target for gdb to debug a modified bootloader program. There is a bug in the program that causes it to run in an infinite loop.

My plan is to interrupt qemu a number of times to see which region of code is causing the execution in an infinite loop.
**How to interrupt qemu by pressing a key to examine the processor state?**

Once interrupted, I know how to examine the registers etc using gdb, but I don't know how to interrupt qemu in the first place. I could not find this info after googling. 
Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I never did this, but AFAIK if you are connecting GDB to QEMU-s built-in gdb "stub" then suspending GDB (by pressing CTRL+C in GDB) should stop QEMU and let you examine the state.

Comment: Did you try control-C? I use it all the time for other emulated processors (ARM, PowerPC, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

**Ctrl + C works** as others mentioned, just as it does on regular userland processes.

Tested with the minimal setup explained on this answer: [How to debug the Linux kernel with GDB and QEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408041/how-to-debug-the-linux-kernel-with-gdb-and-qemu/33203642#33203642)