# Debugging kernel using qemu and gdb

Tags: linux-kernel

I was trying to debug the kernel using *qemu* and *gdb*. For this I have used the concept of bridge connection between *qemu* and *host machine*. In the script I have used the `tcp:17777:127.0.0.1:22` to connect the *qemu* machine for *gdb*.

But when I do `ssh 17777 root@localhost` (*root is user of qemu*), it does not respond me.

**Question 1:** when I will know that I am on right path means I can debug the kernel using *qemu*?

When we do:

1. `gdb vmlinux`
2. `target remote :1234`

**Question 2:** When i try to do `gdb vmlinux` and `target remote :1234` without booting the kernel I want to debug, still I get the following output (which I get when I boot with **qemu** for kernel I want to boot).

```
(gdb) target remote :1234
Remote debugging using :1234
default_idle () at arch/x86/kernel/process.c:299
299         current_thread_info()->status |= TS_POLLING;
```

Help me to understand the concept in detail and share the link to debug kernel using *qemu* and *gdb*

Comment: question 2 : When i try to do gdb vmlinux and target remote :1234 without booting the kernel i want to debug , still i get the following output which i get when I boot with qemu for kernel i want to debug.

Comment: refer similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408041/kernel-debugging-with-gdb-and-qemu

Comment: for complete info take a look at this http://wiki.osdev.org/Kernel_Debugging