# Debugging MINIX OS under VirtualBox

Tags: debugging, virtualbox, minix

How to debug the MINIX kernel under the VirtualBox running on windows, ubuntu, or OSX?

I am using MINIX 3.2.1 and Eclipse CPP.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, debugging an Operating System isn't as simple as debugging an application. Traditionally, Virtual Machines were not available to be used as a debugging tool and so most OS debuggers would simply "test something until it crashed".  Only in recent years have limited tools become available.

Please see this answer on documentation on how to enable a VM debugger on Virtualbox:

- [Tool to Debug Guest OS in Virtual Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045234/tool-to-debug-guest-os-in-virtual-box/8189757#8189757)

(I'm not very familiar with duplicate answer criteria, this question might be considered a duplicate of that).

Please also study the links provided in that questions [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049883) as well.

The OS Dev and Minix Wikis are also good resources for OS development and debugging:

- https://wiki.osdev.org/GDB
- https://wiki.osdev.org/QEMU#GDB-Stub
- https://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:debugging

The rest will likely be up to personal experience, so I hope this is a good place to get you started! Good luck!